# What is "pork brisket?"

Tags: pork, brisket

I picked up a package of "pork brisket" at the supermarket today. I have never seen it before but it was inexpensive and fatty, and looked like a good option to throw in the slow cooker. When my wife saw it, she protested (having raised pigs as a kid): "Anyone who knows about livestock knows that brisket is part of a cow, not part of a pig!"

So, what cut is this, really? Should I treat it like a beef brisket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serious Eats [describes pork brisket this way](http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/05/the-butchers-cuts-pork-brisket.html):

> Pork brisket is simply a substantial part of a boned-out picnic ham.

Although *ham* generally refers to a cured/cooked product, "picnic ham" here refers to the lower part of the pork shoulder:

> [image: Diagram: Cuts of a pork]
>
> **Guide to Pork Cuts**
>
> ...
>
> **Pork Picnic Shoulder** This comes from the lower part of the pig's shoulder. It's usually made into smoked hams, but fresh picnic shoulder makes for very juicy barbecued pulled pork.
>
> <sup>Source: http://austinsfarm.com/GuidetoPork.cfm</sup>

Pork shoulder is a very fatty cut that should be cooked "low and slow" in order to render the fat and break down tough connective tissues. Since beef brisket is also a fatty cut with lots of connective tissue, cooking methods appropriate for beef brisket should also be great for pork brisket (e.g., roasting, smoking or braising).

The [US health department recommends](http://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/mintemp.html) cooking both pork and beef roasts to the same internal temperature of 145 F (63 C) with 3 minutes of resting time. So apart from the differences in texture and flavor that you would expect between pork and beef, you can probably treat these cuts as equivalent.